# using the hover pseudo element doesnt work

Tags: html, css

so I want a hover effect for my navbar so when hovered over a white border bottom shows up but for some reason its not doing that instead it sets the border bottom to white and in other instances does nothing
please help

```css
 nav{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    
    ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .logo{
        margin-left: 35px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .logo:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    li,a{
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }
    
    
    button{
        border-style: none;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 7px;
        padding-right: 7px;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
                    <div class="logo">JEREMY/NDEBELE</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">My Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="nav-button"><a href="contactme.html">CONTACT ME</a></button>
                </nav>
```

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-**class**, not a pseudo-element.

Comment: Also, we can't help you until and unless you post some actual code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: "when hovered over a white border bottom shows up but for some reason its not doing that instead it sets the border bottom to white" - it sounds to me like it's actually doing exactly what you want it to.

Comment: "when hovered over a white border bottom shows up but for some reason its not doing that instead it sets the border bottom to white" i mean it does that on its own without me hovering

Comment: Here your hover works well. And there is no point in specifying `cursor: pointer` for :hover. As this rule will work by default as well. Maybe you wanted different css rules for the :hover?

Comment: maybe there is a problem with the rest of my code

Answer (score 0):

well, I cannot see the hover pseudo anywhere but only on the div with class `logo` and it says `cursor: pointer;`

if you want a hover effect for the navbar so when hovered over a white border bottom shows up

you just need to get the navbar selector added to it `:hover' then add the property` border: solid 1px white` it that simple.